# Vim is creating a .exe file when I run some C++ code. How do I save it to a specific directory?

Tags: key-bindings, external-command, filetype-c++

I have some C++ source code that I am running. I have F9 and F10 mapped to the following in my vimrc file:

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F9> :w <bar> !g++ -std=c++14 % -o %:r -Wl,--stack,268435456<CR>
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F10> :!%:r<CR>
```

Whenever I press F9, a terminal window opens. Afterwards, a .exe file is created in my working directory. Problem is, I don't want this .exe file since it clutters up my workspace. Is there any way I can either turn this off or save specifically the .exe files to a different directory?

Answer (score 2):

Your `g++` command contains `-o %:r`; the `-o` flag for `g++` sets the output filename, the `%` expands to the current buffer name in the Vim commandline, and `:r` is a modifier to remove any file extension. So for `file.cpp` it would be `file`. I assume the `.exe` part is added by g++ automatically on Windows.

To use a different path, well, specify a different path in there  `:help filename-modifiers` contains a list of all modifiers you can use with `%`; and you can test this with `expand()` or `:!echo` (don't forget the `!`! I prefer `expand()` because it's so easy to forget):

```
:echo expand('%')
file.cpp
:echo expand('%:r')
file
```

I don't know what makes sense for you or your projects, but to store files in a `.obj` directory you could for example use:

```
!g++ -std=c++14 % -o .obj/%:r
```

The downside of this is that it won't work if the `.obj` directory doesn't exist yet, so you may want to add that to your keybind:

```
nnoremap <F9> :w <bar> call mkdir('.obj', 'p') <bar> !g++ -std=c++14 % -o %:r -Wl,--stack,268435456<CR>
```

With the `'p'` as the second argument to `mkdir()` you won't get an error if the directory doesn't exist.

You can also store something in your user profile, temp directory, or some other global location on your system:

```
!g++ -std=c++14 % -o $TEMPDIR/%:r
```

I *think* `$TEMPDIR` will expand to the temporary directory on Windows, but I'm not 100% sure so you may want to verify this; but the idea should be clear.